# Whats $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, limits

My thought is that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{|x|}=\infty$. Since $|x|$ can’t be negative, $0$ can only be approached from the positive side. Since one divided by something really close to zero and positive gives a really large number should this limit be equal to $\infty$

Comment: Did you see already the definition of what it means (mathematically speaking) that the limit is $\infty$?

Comment: To be sure you need to use the formal definition of a positive infinite limit.

Comment: Your argument is a reasonably good one from an intuitive perspective. Still, though, if you know the formal definition of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = +\infty$, this is an easy one to verify formally, and it's worth trying.

Comment: A picture is worth an infinite amount of words - graph it and compare to $1/x$ from each side of $0$ - not a proof but immediately tells you the result.

Comment: Why $x$ can't be negative? If so then $|x|$ would simply be $x$. No, it can be negative, and $0$ can be approached from the left side. This doesn't change much, but you should be aware of exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right intuition for this problem. Mathematically, this is formalized by showing that for *any arbitrarily large* constant $F$, your expression will exceed $F$ whenever $|x-a|$ is *sufficiently small*.

In order to make this a formal proof, note the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \infty$:
$$\forall F > 0\,\exists \epsilon > 0:\quad f(x) > F\quad\forall x \text{ with }0<|x-a| < \epsilon.$$ That is: For any arbitrarily large $F$ you can find a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ such that $f(x)>F$ for all $x$ that are closer to $a$ than $\epsilon$ (and $x\neq a$).

Applying this to your problem: Choose any $F>0$, then we may pick $\epsilon = \frac 1F$, and for all $x$ with $ |x - 0| = |x| < \epsilon$ we have $\frac 1{|x|} > F$. Since you can choose $F$ arbitrarily large, this concludes the proof.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics), Section "Infinity in limits of functions" for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question in your question:

[image]

This is the graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$, which approaches $∞$ from either side. Notice that $f(x)>0$ but $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x≠0\}$.